# Read adapter procedure requestTimeoutInSeconds from worklight.properties file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

I am developing a Worklight 6.2 application wherein I have a requirement to read parameters from `worklight.properties` file.

I have successfully read below parameters and set them.

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>${adapter.protocol}</protocol>
        <domain>${adapter.domain}</domain>
        <port>${adapter.port}</port>
    </connectionPolicy>
   <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="200" />
</connectivity>
```

But I am unable to set procedure `requestTimeOutInSeconds` attribute from `worklight.properties` file as below.

```
<procedure name="procedureName" requestTimeoutInSeconds="${procedure.timeout}" />
```

Can I set this using properties from `worklight.properties`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed one of the parameters that you cannot 'externalize' to worklight.properties in order to read its value from a variable.

You can submit a feature request here: http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help